# rename specific file in a folder php

Tags: php

I am trying to practice php language.

How do I rename a specific file in a folder?

This is my code sample

```
if (file_exists("test1/test2/test.txt")) {

$file = "test1/test2/test.txt";
$file_name = "test.txt";
$date = date("h:i:sa d-m-y");
rename($file, $date.$file_name);
}else {
echo "no file";
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0):

Your destination file name does not belong to the original folder your file has. It will move the `$file` to PHP working directory. You need to specific folder for `$file_name`.

Try the following code:

```
$folder = "test/test2/";
$file = $folder . "test.txt";
$date = date("h:i:sa d-m-y");

if (file_exists($file)) {
    $file_name = $folder.$date."new_filename.txt";
    rename($file, $file_name);
}else {
    echo "no file";
}
```

You can check the page here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php